# Is there a way to write dune files programatically from OCaml?

Tags: ocaml, metaprogramming, ocaml-dune

I am generating OCaml code in OCaml. This code includes several Dune files which may be updated and have specific parts change. I am reaching the limit of what I can do with some clever `printf`, and would like to know if there is an easy way to use Dune as a library to programatically create Dune files?

Comment: Is something like: https://jbuilder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-topics.html#ocaml-syntax able to solve your problem?

Comment: what do you mean by "clever printf" ?

Comment: Maybe "clever" was too much, I just meant: writing the dune file using printf. The problem is sometimes I would need to add a library to an existing dune file, so I need to be able to parse it as well as print it.